Forwarding Linux /dev/snd/* and /dev/video* device files over local network from X terminal
I've a 1GB Raspberry Pi 3B that I'd like to use as an X terminal.  One of the things I need to do there is Zoom and Teams meetings.  So I need a way to make /dev/video* and /dev/snd/* at the Pi appear as /dev/videoSOMETHING and /dev/snd/SOMETHING on the application host(s) so that e.g. Zoom on the application host will see devices there that are actually connected to the Pi.  This would be strictly over LAN with plenty of bandwidth available.
Basically I have the Pi 3B (so $0 solution, if it exists, beats buying more hardware) and I need a work station at a particular location, and the Pi struggles just to launch a sizable application so I want to run the application on beefier hardware that I have elsewhere.  This is pretty much exactly what X was made for.  (Also it would be fun to set up an X terminal.)
It looks like 'v4l2loopback' might work for the video, but what about audio?  (And is there something else I should consider for video?)

Did you try the obvious one - ffmpeg?

pulse audio might work for audio. Many applications include it's library due to deficiencies in many Linux sound devices.
